How to find $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos(x^2) - 1}{e^{x^4}-1}$ using power series
How would I find $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos(x^2) - 1}{e^{x^4}-1}$$ using power series? I was working with a few others on this and this is how far we got:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos(x^2) - 1}{e^{x^4}-1} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{4n}) - 1}{(\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{x^{4n}}{n!}) - 1}$$
$$= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{4n}}{\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{x^{4n}}{n!}}$$
We weren't really sure how to proceed from there. One of the people working with me thought we could divide them to get $\lim_{x \to 0} \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n n!}{(2n)!}$, but the rest of didn't think you could do that, because the sums are actually polynomials, and that's not how to perform polynomial long division. And anyways, the result is constant with respect to $x$, which wouldn't make sense. Is there a different way to do this? Our current form still ends up being $\frac 0 0$.

Try dividing top and bottom by $x^4$ and see what happens to each as you take the limit

@Pillsy That's probably an easier solution than the one I went with (in the selected answer); thank you for the contribution!

Before applying series I would use $$ \lim_{x\to 0}{\cos(x^2)-1\over e^{x^4}-1}= \lim_{t\to 0^+}{\cos \sqrt{t}-1\over e^{t}-1}$$

To begin with, notice that
\begin{align*}
\cos(x^{2}) = 1 - \frac{x^{4}}{2!} + \frac{x^{8}}{4!} - \ldots
\end{align*}
as well as
\begin{align*}
e^{x^{4}} = 1 + x^{4} + \frac{x^{8}}{2!} + \ldots
\end{align*}
Consequently, it results that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos(x^{2}) - 1}{e^{x^{4}} - 1} = \lim_{x\to 0}\left(-\frac{x^{4}/2}{x^{4}}\right) = -\frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}
Hopefully this helps!

Can you explain how you got to $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-x^4/2}{x^4}$ in a bit more detail?

That is because $\cos(x^{2}) - 1 \sim -\frac{x^{4}}{2}$ and $e^{x^{4}} - 1 \sim x^{4}$ when $x\to 0$.

Why can we say that? They also both go to 0.

Notice that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{x^{4}} - 1}{x^{4}} = \lim_{x\to 0}\left(1 + \frac{x^{4}}{2!} + \ldots\right) = 1
\end{align*}
Similar approach applies to $\cos(x^{2}) - 1$.

But you can't multiply both sides by $x^4$, because it's inside a limit, so how does that prove that it equals $x^4$?

You can proceed as follows:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos(x^{2}) - 1}{e^{x^{4}} - 1} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos(x^{2}) - 1}{(-x^{4}/2)}\frac{x^{4}}{e^{x^{4}} - 1}\frac{(-x^{4}/2)}{x^{4}}
\end{align*}
and apply the limit properties.

I thought I couldn't say that $\lim a * b = (\lim a)(\lim b)$?

Since all the limits exist as $x$ approaches $0$, you are allowed to apply the product rule.

Oh, I see. Thank you!

You are welcome. If you think it deserves, you can upvote and choose my answer.

I do, actually. Sorry about that, we spent so long in comments that I forgot it existed xD
